Updating campaign member status/activity from Marketing Cloud Send
I have enabled the campaign member integration in my Marketing Cloud Connect settings and I've mapped the various status's to campaign member activity picklist items.
However I'm not entirely sure what fields need to be included in the audience to ensure that when I perform a send from Marketing Cloud that the campaign member activity is updated?
My assumption is that if I perform a send a to Salesforce Data Extension, that only contains contact or lead ID then it wouldnt be able to update the campaign member status as the campaign ID or campaign member ID is not available. Is this correct?
I also assume that if I send to the salesforce campaign directly it would work.
However is there any middle ground? What fields could I add to my Salesforce Data Extension to ensure the campaign member activity is updated in Salesforce?
Thanks

Does this answer your question? Automating Updating Campaign Members - SFMC to SFDC
